# Is there any place in an AdS Universe with positive spacial curvature?

Tags: general-relativity, anti-de-sitter-spacetime

An AdS space has constant negative curvature, gravitational objects introduce more negative curvature.  Therefor it seems like it is possible that everywhere in the Universe has negaative curvature (of space not space-time), and it only depends on to what degree. i.e. for the ricci sacalar $R<0$ everywhere and always and $\sqrt{-R}$ would always be well defined.

For a de-sitter space, one could imagine that the gravity of objects could cancel out the positive curvature of de-sitter space and so you would have areas where $R$ changed sign.

If we ignore quantum fluctuations (i.e. only consider classical equations), is this assumption correct that AdS space has no areas of zero or positive curvature?

Since it is believed we live in dS not AdS space, this should mean that the sign of $R$ can change from place to place. Is this true?

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly. I don't wish to exclude neutron stars if they can be considerd in a semi-classical way without talking about quantum foam etc. Indeed it would be illuminating if neutron stars provided a counter example.

Comment: Won't the spatial curvature will depend on your coordinate slicing of the spacetime? I suspect you can always choose a slicing where in some small region, the curvature of a spacelike hypersurface has an arbitrary form.

Comment: What do you mean by the spatial curvature? Do you mean the spatial components of the Riemann tensor for the full spacetime? Or do you mean the extrinsic curvature of a spacelike hypersurface? Both are coordinate dependent, but they are different beasts.

Comment: I take back my comment about neutron stars. I overlooked the fact that the question is asking about *spatial* curvature (cf @Andrew's comments).